# PHPSpreadsheet - Read format code of a cell always give me "General"

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have an excel file where I can have percentages sometimes.
I want to check if a cell's format is percentage and if it is, I want to change it from 0.08 to 8% for example.

But when I get the FormatCode like this :

```php
$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $key)->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

I always get "*General*" instead of "*Percentage*" even if in my file it is "percentage".
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Make sure you have the line `$reader->setReadDataOnly(FALSE);` before the getFormatCode statement, otherwise the system will ignore formatting

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is it !